# Is setting tax rates to Client only Stripe Checkout (no Sessions) Subscription possible?

Tags: stripe-payments, checkout, tax-rate

I'm trying to implement Stripe Checkout without server integration (client-only).  It seems like I cannot set tax rates when I call [redirectToCheckout](https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout).

I've searched similar questions like the following but they aren't client-only and are using Sessions:

[Stripe Checkout - Create Session - Apply Tax Rates on subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57184491/stripe-checkout-create-session-apply-tax-rates-on-subscriptions)

[Tax Rate in new Stripe Checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097929/tax-rate-in-new-stripe-checkout)

[This documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/taxes?tax-calculation=tax-rates) seems to mention tax rates in Stripe Checkout but is using Sessions as well.
I couldn't find any documentation saying **it is not possible** so I've decided to ask here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use Stripe Tax or tax rates with client-only Checkout. This is one of many limitations highlighted [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/client). Stripe generally advises against using client-only Checkout for these reasons.

If you'd prefer to integrate without a server component, then I recommend using [Payment Links](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links), which support taxes, instead.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I missed that part and am glad to know it isn't possible for sure.

As for Payment Links, from the documentation, I assume that it is only possible to integrate with Stripe Tax (which is a paid service) and not plain Tax Rates?

I've found it mentioned in the link you shared:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-links#taxes

Comment: Yep, Payment Links only has support for Stripe Tax. If you'd prefer to use tax rates then you'd need to create a Checkout Session (server-side).